# Can 'return' return multiple values in C?

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ — return x,y; What is the point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539458/c-return-x-y-what-is-the-point)

Here's a piece of code that executes perfectly in C.

```
int a=3,b=4,x,y;
x=a+b;
y=a*b;
return(x,y);
```

This function returns 12. Can someone please explain.

Comment: You appear to be asking two different questions here.

Comment: This has already been asked. Here's the answer: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539458/c-return-x-y-what-is-the-point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539458/c-return-x-y-what-is-the-point)

Answer (score 15):

This is because you (inadvertently) use the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator), whose value is that of the last expression included. You can list as many expressions as you like, separated by the comma operator, the result is always that of the last expression. This is not related to `return`; your code can be rewritten like

```
int tmp = (x, y); // x = 7, y = 12 -> tmp is assigned 12
return tmp;
```

**[Updated]** You don't usually need brackets around the list, but here you do, due to the assignment operator having a higher precedence than comma - kudos to @Draco for pointing it out.

Comment: @Draco, you are right, thanks :-) I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Edit : This answers the title Q, viz 'can return return multiple values'
Not exactly. You can

1. return the second variable by using reference (or pointer) parameter
2. otherwise, create a new class or struct containing x and y and return an instance of this new class

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot return multiple values simply by using `(x, y)` — this is not a tuple, as you might expect from other languages, but a bracketed use of the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator), which will simply evaluate to `y` (which will, in turn, be returned by the `return`).

If you want to return multiple values, you should [create a `struct`](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter6/structures.html), like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct coordinate
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

struct coordinate myfunc(int a, int b)
{
    struct coordinate retval = { a + b , a * b };
    return retval;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct coordinate coord = myfunc(3, 4);
    printf("X: %d\n", coord.x);
    printf("Y: %d\n", coord.y);
}
```

This shows the full syntax of using a struct, but you can [use `typedef`](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter8/typedef.html) if you prefer something like:

```
typedef struct
{
    int x;
    int y;
} coordinate;

coordinate myfunc(int a, int b)
{
    coordinate retval = { a + b , a * b };
    return retval;
}

// ...etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is "no, return cannot return multiple values".  Here you see the result of the evaluation of the legal expression `x,y`, which is `y` i.e. 3*4 = 12.

Answer (score 1):

The [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) is just a binary operator.  The right-most value is returned.

Answer (score 0):

That's the comma operator. It evaluates its left side, then evaluates its right side, and its resulting value is the right side.

So, `return(x,y)` is the same as `return y`, since evaluating `x` has no side-effects.

The only way to "return multiple values" in C is to return a struct by value:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int sum;
    int product;
} sumprod;

sumprod get_sum_and_product(int x, int y) {
    sumprod ret = {x + y, x * y};
    return ret;
}

int main() {
    sumprod values = get_sum_and_product(3,4);
    printf("sum is %d, product is %d\n", values.sum, values.product);
}
```